# Changing DropDown Values using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I cannot somehow change my DropDown Options using AJAX, I can however use my current Model's to populate on form initialize but "OnChange" the dropdown just resets to NULL instead of populating the DropDown Field.

this is part of my FORM VIEW...

```
<div class="field_row clearfix">
<?php echo form_label($this->lang->line('expenses_exp_by').':', 'exp_by_id',array('class'=>'required wide')); ?>
    <div class='form_field'>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('exp_by_id', $company, $selected_company, 'id="exp_by_id"');?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field_row clearfix">
<?php echo form_label($this->lang->line('expenses_product').':', 'prod_id',array('class'=>'required wide')); ?>
    <div class='form_field'>
    <?php //echo form_dropdown('prod_id', $product, $selected_product, 'id="prod_id"');?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('prod_id', $product, '', 'id="prod_id"');?>
    </div>
</div>


    <script>

        $('#exp_by_id').change(function(){ 

            $("#prod_id > option").remove(); 
            var exp_by_id = $('#exp_by_id').val();  
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "expenses/get_products_by_client_ajax/"+exp_by_id, 
                success: function(prod_id)             { 
                    $.each(prod_id,function(prod_id,prod_name) 
                    { 
                        var opt = $('<option />'); 
                        opt.val(prod_id); 
                        opt.text(prod_name); 
                        $('#prod_id').append(opt); 
                    }); 
                } 

            }); 

        }); 
    </script>
```

this is my CONTROLLER

```
function get_products_by_client_ajax($exp_by_id = -1){ 


        //$exp_by_id = $this->Expense->get_info($exp_id)->exp_by_id;
        foreach($this->Expense->get_products_by_client($exp_by_id)->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $prod_name[$row['prod_id']] = $row['prod_name'];
        }
        return $prod_name;
}
```

this is my Model

```
function get_products_by_client($exp_by_id)
    {

        $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT  prod_id, prod_name
        FROM    products
        WHERE   client_id = ".$exp_by_id);

        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Your ajax expects a json response, are you returning json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax request doesn't need to be post, it can be GET.  Also, you should specify your expected data type.  Also, you're using `prod_id` in two different contexts, which is confusing and error-prone.

Try this for your ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET", 
            dataType: "json", 
            url: "expenses/get_products_by_client_ajax/"+exp_by_id, 
            success: function(products) { 
                $.each(products,function(prod_id,prod_name) 
                { 
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(prod_id); 
                    opt.text(prod_name); 
                    $('#prod_id').append(opt); 
                }); 
            } 

        });
```

In your controller, you want to json-encode your output:

```
    return json_encode($prod_name);
```